# Correct way to add a pointer to an empty std::list using push_back

Tags: c++, list, std, allocator

I have two simple classes representing nodes and edges in a connected graph structure.

```
//node.h

#include "edge.h"
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <utility> 

using namespace std; 

class Edge;

class Node {
private:
    list<Edge> edgeList;
    string nodeName; 
    pair <int, int> coordinates;
public:
    Node();
    void setXY(int x, int y);
    void insertEdge(Edge& edgeToAdd);
    void removeEdge(Edge& edgeToAdd);
    list<Edge> getEdgeList();
};
```

With `insertEdge` method implemented in node.cpp as:

```
void Node::insertEdge(Edge& edgeToAdd) {
    this->edgeList.push_back(edgeToAdd);
}
```

The `Edge` class is another simple class declared in edge.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "node.h"

class Node; 

class Edge {
private:
    Node* destinationNode;
    int edgeWeight;
public:
    //constructor
    Edge(Node* destNode, int w);

    //Setters and Getters 
    void setDestinationNode(Node* destNode);
    void setEdgeWeight(int weight);
    Node* getDestinationNode();
    int getEdgeWeight();
};
```

In another file in which I am writing unit tests I try to insert a pointer to an edge object using the `insertEdge` method detailed above:

```
SECTION("an edge gets inserted to the adjacency list") 
{
        Node* b = &Node();
        Edge* e = new Edge(b,1);
        b->insertEdge(*e);
        list<Edge> edgelist = b->getEdgeList();
}
```

I have determined that `edgeList.push_back(edgeToAdd)` results in a segmentation fault due to illegal memory access. Stepping through the code I can see that the variables which are being illegally accessed are `_Prev` and `_Next` which are members of the allocator of the std::list. I suspect that my problem has something to do with how I have declared `std::list<Edge*> edgeList`

My question is, what is a correct way to add a pointer to a std::list which has only being declared?

Comment: `Node* b = &Node();` should not compile, it is taking the address of a temporary object that goes out of scope as soon as that full expression ends.

Comment: @NathanOliver am I correct in saying that only Node* b = new Node() would be a correct usage? In that case the memory would be allocated on the heap and not get released as soon as the full expression ends.

Comment: Yes, that would keep the pointer pointing to a valid object.

Comment: Side note: The linked-list (or linked list-like) `std::list` is really slow unless you are performing inserts or removals at an already known location. As soon as you have to iterate or find stuff, you lose and lose hard compared to an array-like `std::vector`. `list` does have wonderfully forgiving  [iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/4581301), though.

Comment: @Blargian `In that case the memory would be allocated on the heap and not get released as soon as the full expression ends` you should stop thinking about heap and stack when you are talking about the lifetime of objects, instead use [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration). It might be true that storage duration and stack/heap are often related but that's not always the case. stack/heap: where the data is stored based on the implementation, storage duration: describes the lifetime of objects.

Comment: `Edge* e = new Edge(b, 1); b->insertEdge(*e);` There's no reason to dynamically-allocate your `Edge` here.  You're inserting a copy of it into the `Node`'s `edgeList`, so you may as well just use a local with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is the way you did it.

However, this line:

```
Node* b = &Node();
```

creates a new `Node`, gets its address, then destroys that node because it was only a temporary object. Then you access the list inside that destroyed `Node`.

You probably wanted to write `Node b;` and then use `b.` instead of `b->` - this creates a `Node` in a local variable that stays alive until the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue. I'm trying to do an adjacency list implementation of a graph here, so I originally had in mind storing pointers to nodes in the edge list. I have in my mind for some reason that not making copies but rather using pointers or references is more efficient. However If the Node object will only stay alive until the function end I'm thinking it would be better to rather store copies of Nodes in the edge list?

Comment: @Blargian do you *want* to store copies of nodes in the edge list? (does that include copies of their edge lists including copies of the edge lists including copies of the copies of the other nodes? going on forever? creating infinite copies?) If not, what do you actually want to do?